# CodeIgniter upload function, sometime not works

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I have problem with codeigniter upload function.
The function works well, but sometimes didn't work and without any error info.

snippet in controller

```
...
        function add_process() {
                $data['title'] = anchor('event/','<b>EVENT</b>', array('class' => 'back'));
                $data['subtitle'] = ' / Add Event';
                $data['main_view'] = 'event/event_form';
                $data['form_action'] = site_url('event/add_process');       

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('eventName', 'Event Name', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('eventDate', 'Event Date', 'required');
                if (empty($_FILES['eventImage']['name'])){
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('eventImage', 'Event Image', 'required');     
                }               

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {    
                    $config['upload_path'] = './images/event/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';          
                    //$config['max_width'] = '3000';
                    //$config['max_height'] = '3000';

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    $this->upload->do_upload('eventImage');
                    $eventImage = $this->upload->data();

                    $event = array( 'eventName'         => $this->input->post('eventName'),
                                    'eventDate'         => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('eventDate'))),
                                    'eventDescriptions' => $this->input->post('eventDescriptions'),
                                    'eventImage'        => 'images/event/'.$eventImage['file_name'],
                                    'isActive'          => $this->input->post('isActive')
                                );
                    $this->Event_model->add($event);            

                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 record was successfully added!');
                    redirect('event/add');      

                } else  {           
                    $this->load->view('admin/admin_main', $data);
                }
            } 
    ...
```

could you tell please, what am i missing here?

Comment: Replace `$this->upload->do_upload('eventImage');` with `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('eventImage')) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    var_dump($error);
}` to see what errors you have.

Comment: ah i see, this is for catch the error, right? i'll let you know if the function showing error. thanks @Mirceac21

Comment: actually has found the problem, someone has remove the comment tag at $config['max_width'] = '3000'. So when try upload a huge image, the problem occurs. PS: and the someone is me, what a ...

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
$this->Event_model->add($event);            

$this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 record was successfully added!');
redirect('event/add');
```

to this

```
if ($this->Event_model->add($event)) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 record was successfully added!');
    redirect('event/add'); 
}
```